# Will an app made for windows store support WindowsRT, windows8 and windows 8 mobile?

Tags: windows-8, winrt, windows-phone-8

I am very much confused about these.

I would like to develop app for windows 8 , Windows RT , and windows mobile. 
I have windows 8 OS installed in my laptop.

As far as I know, Windows RT is for ARM based devices.

HERE ARE MY QUESTIONS:

1. I develop an app, and put in windows store. Will that can be downloaded from a ARM based device ,which runs on Windows RT, AND from a windows 8 laptop , and same from a Windows 8 mobile?

OR should it be different apps ?

Comment: Can anyone explain why this is off topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Windows RT and Windows Phone are different ecosystems and different APIs.

WinRT is application runtime for running "Modern UI" apps in Windows 8 and Windows RT. It is actually only way to create a 3rd party application for Windows RT. Those apps must always be run from withing "Modern UI" of Windows, eg. it is not possible to use it from desktop application.

For Windows 8 Mobile, you need to use WinPRT. This is derived from WinRT, but is binary incompatible and contains different APIs and UI controls. But it is somehow similliar so you can share pieces of code between them.

More here:

- http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-043

Comment: Thanks @Euphoric .. So an app ( with WinRT ) will run in both Windows 8 and in Windows RT , Am I correct? ie Windows8 would be able to handle normal desktop applications + winRT apps.

Comment: @AnhSirkDasarp- Yes of course it will.